# Create random background on one section of a single-page scroll website

Tags: css, image, background, background-image

I'm looking for code to randomize a background image on one section of a single-page scroll website. I have researched ways of doing this (php/js/html stuff; [one ex](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/), [second ex](http://www.thought-after.com/2006/05/css-random-background-image-rotation/)), but I couldn't get it them to work because I don't want the images to apply to all of the pages/sections and I don't want it in the "body" of the HTML." Please advise!

Currently, I change the background in the CSS with `backgound-image` code of a single class.

Comment: When you say randomize the background do you mean on load of the page, or while scrolling, both would be handled differently.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "one section of the website"?

Comment: @chris: I mean on page load. Thanks for your question.

Comment: @Misch: Since it's a single-page scroll website, each page is really just a section of the same page. You can view it at jacklynn.com/thirdprinciple if it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the PHP code for randomizing background images:

```
<?php

$bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' ); // array of filenames

$i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
$selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen        
?>
```

And:

```
<style type="text/css">
.mydiv{
    background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}
</style>
<div class="mydiv">

</div>
```

---

This is the JavaScript and JQuery solution for randomizing background images:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
$('.mydiv').css({
    'background-image': 'url(/path/to/images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() *      images.length)] + ')'
});
</script>
```

See this in action (hit run in top left to randomize the image): http://jsfiddle.net/Kf6sb/

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I guess the problem is that nothing shows up. If it helps, you can view the website here: jacklynn.com/thirdprinciple.

I put the code you have in place, and deleted the 'background-image' from the css, but nothing still showed up (I put it back for now because my client is getting feed back on the site now). But you can still see the code in the HTML in the '.top' class. Maybe I am doing it wrong?

Comment: I noticed I accidentally didn't change both div names, so I changed it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Your PHP code isn't running on the server, it's just printing it out as text. So that is the problem. You'd have to call your host and figure out why PHP is not running if you want to use the above code. OR you can use a pure JavaScript solution. I'll update my answer with how to do that.

Comment: Justin, thanks so so much for your advice, but it's still not working. I feel like it's not pulling the images. It would move stuff around because of 300px div, but no image would be inside of it. 

So I tried the second thing you suggested by putting in this code where `.top` is the current div where everything sits:
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var images = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'];
$('.top').css({
    'background-image': 'url(/css/img/bg' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() *      images.length)] + ')'
});
</script>`

I suck.

Comment: Change `/css/img/bg` to `css/img/bg/` OR `/thirdprinciple/css/img/bg/`

Comment: Also, you should remove the PHP code from your page, looks like you have it in there a couple of times.

Comment: Ahhh! Justin I love you! Ok, it wasn't working when I was doing it locally, but then I thought I would just try editing it live and it totally works! Thanks so much!!! I also deleted the errant php files. (sorry for the delayed response, I got caught up with other work)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with javascript/jquery as well. Very similar to Justin's above except it wouldnt be handled by PHP, and there would be no need for in page css either.

```
var uri = 'http://example.com';
var img_folder = '/images/';
var img_files = ['bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg'];

function randomBackground()
{
   var random_image = img_files[Math.floor(Math.random()*img_files.length)];
   $('body').css({"background-image":"url("+random_image+")"});
}

//when the page loads
$(document).ready(function()
{
    randomBackground();
});

//an example of changing it on a timer at random
setInterval(function(){randomBackground();}, 300000);

//example of changing it on click
$('#someIDofSomeElement').click(function(){randomBackground();}
```

Its worth mentioning this is pure concept, not tested, but something to the extent of this, if not this specifically should work. But again, this isn't a set in stone method either as demonstrated above theres ways with PHP, or any language to do it, theres also likely a dozen and one ways I can think of to add to this, do it differently, or do with it.

Comment: Chris, how would I would connect this to the appropriate page? I see the `#someIDofSomeElement` but would that work for part of a single-page scroll? I was a little confused on how to implement this suggestion, but thank you.

Comment: Well the above code would only change the background-image.. the rest of the css pertaining to the body and its properties can be left in an external CSS file, to keep the background from moving you would do something like `body{background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;}` applying a style in a style sheet wont make change what the JS is doing.

Comment: Also I noticed a minor mistake in my code above I adjusted it,